# How to resolve problem when app is published to Expo and others can't have access?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I have pushed and published my IOS app to Expo using CLI and got my link for hosting. When I try to open the app, everything is ok.

When others try to open an app from the expo site, they get this error:

**The experience you requested is not viable by you. You will need to log in or ask the owner to grant you access.**

Problem is that user is already logged in with Expo app on IOS.

My project is public and here is my app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "PassApp",
    "description": "Simple QR code scanning app",
    "slug": "ExpoClinicQr",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "31.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  },
  "infoPlist": {
    "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to scan barcodes for clinic."
  }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue even I am facing this problem.

Comment: @Pikachu-go yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

Basically, you need to give others your Expo username/password because others can't open the Expo project with their credentials.

Another solution is to go with the Testflight and add users there.